# Deploying MVC app to Azure App Services Error - subscription is not registered for the resource type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to public an MVC application to azure from Visual Studio 2015 directly.*[Right click project > Publish > To Azure]*
Every time i try to Publish my web application to my azure account i get the following error:

```
**The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in the location 'Central US'. Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location.**
```

I have tried to use multiple locations to host the application and the error still continues

**Q:** How does one register for this component? (i have not included application insights in my application on creation)

Below is more details around the error:

```
OPERATION IDC16287A675C4B7D3
TRACKING IDb0355f45-867b-4328-95cd-6d627751c619
STATUSConflict
PROVISIONING STATEFailed
TIMESTAMP12/3/2016, 3:12:24 PM
DURATIONPT0.8505384S
TYPEmicrosoft.insights/components
RESOURCE ID/subscriptions/a955ba0f-a5f6-4ba4-b7d4-a0dae7b87215/resourceGroups/DemoBEEApp1Resources/providers/microsoft.insights/components/DemoBEEApp2
STATUSMESSAGE{
  "error": {
    "code": "MissingRegistrationForLocation",
    "message": "The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in the location 'Central US'. Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location."
  }
}
RESOURCEDemoBEEApp2
```

When i try find the areas supported using the powershell command:

```
((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace microsoft.insights).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).Locations
```

The result comes back blank.

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwJoH.png)

**Q:** What is this microsoft.insights and why is it automatically required but not available?

I really hope somebody can assist me

Comment: Tracked by [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d71994f3-5b2e-4801-9b07-1eec36cffd38/deploying-mvc-app-to-azure-app-services-error-subscription-is-not-registered-for-the-resource-type?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). Would be best to keep in one place.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that with PowerShell or Azure CLI, or you could just deploy the WebApp once using the Portal.

```
$providers = @(Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable)
foreach ($x in $providers) {

Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace $x.ProviderNamespace -Force
write-host $x.ProviderNamespace
}
Write-Host “Done!”
```

Here's the link to the [Azure CLI commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-cli-arm-commands?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json#azure-provider-commands-to-manage-resource-provider-registrations).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am very new to Azure. Could you possibly explain how i implement or execute the above code you have proposed? I followed the instructions in the link and installed and loged in to my azure account but further than that i am lost

Comment: Sure, do you have access to Azure Portal? Can you login to portal.azure.com? If you can, go there and create a WebApp in any region, it will register the provider for you automatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-create-web-app-from-marketplace but create WebApp.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i have access to the portal. That was initially my first resort but when i do that  i cant find the created web app from my visual studio publish process. I really want to be able to publish straight from visual studio.

Comment: ok, can we talk on skype or whatever? this won't be productive this way :)

Comment: I would appreciate that thanks. my Skype  name is +27834411232

Comment: @Keith messaged you, no answer.

Comment: I havnt got a message, could you try email keith@qaf.co.za, would really apreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the latest version of Azure Tools and the location problem was resolved. A new error occurred when trying to create a new Azure web app from visual studio

[image: Screenshot]

However at least now i can publish to Azure using web deploy

Comment: It seems that the error message is not related to original one. It will be also more helpful for other communities, If you could create another thread in the SO